NotADirectoryError Raised When Directory Exists
I have a directory that exists. Python couldn't find it, but it exists.
Directory:
data
  images
    entities
      player.png

But Python can't find "data/images/entities/player.png":
NotADirectoryError: Not a directory: 'data/images/entities/player.png'

I tried to switch a directory, but the output was a FileNotFoundError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/Desktop/Aiden/slime invasion/main.py", line 70, in <module>
    Game().run()
    ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/*****/Desktop/Aiden/slime invasion/main.py", line 22, in __init__
    'player': load_images('entities/player/left/0.png'),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/*****/Desktop/Aiden/slime invasion/utils.py", line 12, in load_images
    for file in os.listdir(BASE_IMAGE_PATH + path):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/images/entities/player/left/0.png'

Why?

Use a full path, not a relative one.

There was no file data/images/entities/player/left/0.png relative to the working directory from where the script was executed.

@mkrieger1 there's no guarantee the current working directory is even where the script was executed.

@MarkRansom from where ;-)

Execution Space

If you use the CMD

And your on windows, you need to Right Click in the folder and Open in the terminal
If your on linux, (i think i know) get the folder path and type "cd (your path)"


If you're using VSCode to execute your code, you need to Open with Code in your folder, make sure you main .py is in the folder you opened with VSCode

Path
And try adding a / to your path "/data/images/entities/player.png" or "/entities/player/left/0.png", this worked for me.
